# Is there a specific term for a graph having equal slopes at the same y-value? (See picture)

Tags: analysis, graphing-functions, economics, slope

In my urban economics course, we looked at the preceding graph. My professor stated that a key assumption/reason the model is unstable at certain points is that the slopes differ (in absolute value) between two points on the same $y=a$ counter line (the red line in graph) (see the graphics below). Notice that the point on the left of the graph has a steep slope, while the point on the right has a lesser slope.

Is there a mathematical term for the case when the slope of a curve like this is equal at two different values of $x$ that yield the same $y$ value?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a standard mathematical term for that.

Comment: It seems you want the slopes to be exactly opposite (same absolute value, different signs). I think "exactly opposite slopes at [any/some/the given] value of $y$" might be a good way to describe what you mean, but that's not exactly a specific mathematical term like "decreasing function" or "local maximum".

Comment: The slope of a curve can't be equal to two different values of $x$. Slopes are numbers that either look like $\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ (in the secant case) or like $y'(x)$ (in the tangent case). Slopes are not $x$ values, nor are they $y$ values. Could you please reword your question?

Answer (score 1):

The everywhere differentiable functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=f(y)\implies f'(x)=f'(y)$ are exactly the (not necessarily strictly) increasing/decreasing functions.

If you want $f(x)=f(y)\implies|f'(x)|=|f'(y)|$  then the characterization is not so easy anymore. All these functions look probably something like this:

[image]

They can have plateaus and the left and right slope are identical. I think there is no established name in the literature for such functions.

---

In your context I would say you are looking for *even functions*, i.e. if $a$ is the maximum, then there holds $f(a-x)=f(a+x)$.